# How to access value from a ComboBox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I want to know how to access the value of a ComboBox. I tried several syntax possibillities and couldnt find a solution online. In future I need the value of two ComboBox to add new rows to a table.

```
    Sub add_termin()
    
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim typ As String
        Dim frist As Date
        Dim tops As String
        
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Set diesesworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        lastrow = diesesworkbook.Sheets("Termine").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        typ = ComboBox1.Column(1).Value
        MsgBox (lastrow)

'Hinzufügen neuer Zeile
    'diesesworkbook.Sheets("Termine").Range("A" & (lastrow + 1)).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    'diesesworkbook.Sheets("Termine").Range("B" & (lastrow + 1)).Value = TestBox1.Value
    'diesesworkbook.Sheets("Termine").Range("C" & (lastrow + 1)).Value = ComboBox2.Value
```

Edit:

Solution I found was to add the UserForm infront of the ComboBox

```
typ = Termineingabe.ComboBox1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example how to get the column values of the selected index

```
Sub ShowContent()
Dim x As ComboBox
Set x = ActiveSheet.ComboBox1
Debug.Print x.List(x.ListIndex, 0) ' zero based
If x.ColumnCount > 1 Then Debug.Print x.List(x.ListIndex, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really enoying, but thank you.

Comment: Why is this is really enoying?

Comment: Such a long code block for such a simple thing. But I got it working with shorter adjustment; see my edit.